# SQL query to allow NULL for a highest_bid column when no bid has been placed yet

Tags: sql, search, null

For school I need to make a function on an auction website. For this I need to join a couple of tables in a VIEW. This worked just fine, until I needed to add a filter for price range. Seems easy enough but the query result needs to allow a NULL when no bid has been placed.

The Statement for the View:

```
SELECT I.itemID, I.title, I.startPrice, B.highestBid, Cfi.category, I.endDate
FROM dbo.Items AS I INNER JOIN dbo.category_for_item AS Cfi ON V.itemID = Vir.itemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Bid AS B ON V.itemID = B.itemID
```

This would get the following Table:

```
    itemID  title   startPrice  highestBid  category    endDate
1   1234    Alfa    25          26          PC          2018-09-22
2   1234    Alfa    25          NULL        PC          2018-09-22
3   5678    Bravo   9           20          Console     2018-07-03
4   5678    Bravo   9           15          Console     2018-07-03
5   5678    Bravo   9           NULL        Console     2018-07-03
6   9876    Charlie 84          100         Stamps      2018-06-14
7   9876    Charlie 84          90          Stamps      2018-06-14
8   9876    Charlie 84          85          Stamps      2018-06-14
9   9876    Charlie 84          NULL        Stamps      2018-06-14
10  1470    Delta   98          100         Fashion     2018-06-15
11  1470    Delta   98          99          Fashion     2018-06-15
12  1470    Delta   98          NULL        Fashion     2018-06-15
13  9631    Echo    56          65          Cars        2018-06-25
14  9631    Echo    56          NULL        Cars        2018-06-25
15  7856    Foxtrot 98          NULL        Dolls       2018-12-26
```

After looking around for answers I got a query for joining the VIEW on itself with only showing the highest bid instead of all bids:

```
SELECT VW.itemID, VW.title, VW.startPrice, VW.highestBid, VW.category, VW.endDate
FROM VW_SEARCH AS VW
   INNER JOIN (SELECT itemID, MAX(highestBid) AS MaxBid
                    FROM VW_SEARCH
                    GROUP BY itemID) VJ
        ON VW.itemID = VJ.itemID AND VW.highestBid = VJ.MaxBid
```

This gave the next results:

```
    itemID  title   startPrice  highestBid  category    endDate
1   1234    Alfa    25          26          PC          2018-09-22
2   5678    Bravo   9           20          Console     2018-07-03
3   9876    Charlie 84          85          Stamps      2018-06-14
4   1470    Delta   98          100         Fashion     2018-06-15
5   9631    Echo    56          65          Cars        2018-06-25
```

As I expected the result only showed the items with at least one bid on them. I tried added one extra condition on the subQuery and Joining RIGHT OUTER to make sure I would not get doubles of an itemID.

```
SELECT VW.itemID, VW.title, VW.startPrice, VW.highestBid, VW.category, VW.endDate
FROM VW_SEARCH AS VW
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT itemID, MAX(highestBid) AS MaxBid
                    FROM VW_SEARCH
                    WHERE highestBid > 0 OR highestBid IS NULL
                    GROUP BY itemID) VJ
        ON VW.itemID = VJ.itemID AND VW.highestBid = VJ.MaxBid
```

This gave the following results (did not add result 5 - 1199 because it is all the same as result 4, this would happen in the actual table not the example table from above):

```
         itemID title   startPrice  highestBid  category    endDate
1       1234    Alfa    25          26          PC          2018-09-22
2       5678    Bravo   9           20          Console     2018-07-03
3       9876    Charlie 84          85          Stamps      2018-06-14
4       NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
1200    1470    Delta   98          100         Fashion     2018-06-15
1201    9631    Echo    56          65          Cars        2018-06-25
```

While this is technicly allowing a NULL in the colums I need to get a result in the likes of :

```
    itemID  title   startPrice  highestBid  catgory endDate
1   1234    Alfa    25          26          PC          2018-09-22
2   5678    Bravo   9           20          Console     2018-07-03
3   9876    Charlie 84          85          Stamps      2018-06-14
4   1470    Delta   98          100         Fashion     2018-06-15
5   9631    Echo    56          65          Cars        2018-06-25
6   7856    Foxtrot 98          NULL        Dolls       2018-12-26
```

How do I get the desired result, or is it just impossible?
Also if the query could be written better, please say so.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem using a `left join`:

```
SELECT VW.itemID, VW.title, VW.startPrice, VW.highestBid, VW.category, VW.endDate
FROM VW_SEARCH VW LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT itemID, MAX(highestBid) AS MaxBid
      FROM VW_SEARCH
      GROUP BY itemID
     ) VJ
     ON VW.itemID = VJ.itemID AND VW.highestBid = VJ.MaxBid;
```

Or, use the ANSI-standard `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
select vw.*
from (select vw.*,
             row_number() over (partition by itemID
                                order by highestBid nulls last
                               ) as seqnum
      from vw_search vw
     ) vw
where seqnum = 1;
```

This guarantees one row per item.

Note:  Not all databases support `NULLS LAST`.  This may not even be necessary, but you can also implement it using a `case` expression.

Comment: I didn't understand the Select query right away, but after puzzling with it a bit I found out that i indeed needed to use the case version. Works like a charm, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the definition of the view at least? Maybe the table definition too.

Comment: I added the create statement and an example table. I stupidly just forgot the add it. Thanks for mentioning that

Answer (score 0):

I would go only with `subquery` as because *identity* column :

```
select vw.*
from vw_search vw
where id = (select vm1.id
            from vw_search vm1
            where vm.itemID = vw1.itemID and vm1.highestBid is not null
            order by vm1.highestBid desc
            limit 1
           );
```

However, some `DBMS` has not support `LIMIT` clause such as SQL Server if so, then you can use `TOP` clause instead.